# pytorch sdpa compatibility with relative positional embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface, self-attention

Hi Still confused on whether it is possible for rotary and relative positional embeddings to be integrated with the fast kernels in pytorch sdpa, allowing for faster training/inference? If so what would be a blue print of how to merge previous architecture that use both to the new sdpa one ?

I would want to integrate sdpa into the ESM model, available on huggingface at https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/model_doc/esm. Here is the section of the code of interest, the forward call of the attention

```
def forward(
    self,
    hidden_states: torch.Tensor,
    attention_mask: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
    head_mask: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
    encoder_hidden_states: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
    encoder_attention_mask: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
    past_key_value: Optional[Tuple[Tuple[torch.FloatTensor]]] = None,
    output_attentions: Optional[bool] = False,
) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor]:
    mixed_query_layer = self.query(hidden_states)

    # If this is instantiated as a cross-attention module, the keys
    # and values come from an encoder; the attention mask needs to be
    # such that the encoder's padding tokens are not attended to.
    is_cross_attention = encoder_hidden_states is not None

    if is_cross_attention and past_key_value is not None:
        # reuse k,v, cross_attentions
        key_layer = past_key_value[0]
        value_layer = past_key_value[1]
        attention_mask = encoder_attention_mask
    elif is_cross_attention:
        key_layer = self.transpose_for_scores(self.key(encoder_hidden_states))
        value_layer = self.transpose_for_scores(self.value(encoder_hidden_states))
        attention_mask = encoder_attention_mask
    elif past_key_value is not None:
        key_layer = self.transpose_for_scores(self.key(hidden_states))
        value_layer = self.transpose_for_scores(self.value(hidden_states))
        key_layer = torch.cat([past_key_value[0], key_layer], dim=2)
        value_layer = torch.cat([past_key_value[1], value_layer], dim=2)
    else:
        key_layer = self.transpose_for_scores(self.key(hidden_states))
        value_layer = self.transpose_for_scores(self.value(hidden_states))

    query_layer = self.transpose_for_scores(mixed_query_layer)

    # Matt: Our BERT model (which this code was derived from) scales attention logits down by sqrt(head_dim).
    # ESM scales the query down by the same factor instead. Modulo numerical stability these are equivalent,
    # but not when rotary embeddings get involved. Therefore, we scale the query here to match the original
    # ESM code and fix rotary embeddings.
    query_layer = query_layer * self.attention_head_size**-0.5

    if self.is_decoder:
        # if cross_attention save Tuple(torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor) of all cross attention key/value_states.
        # Further calls to cross_attention layer can then reuse all cross-attention
        # key/value_states (first "if" case)
        # if uni-directional self-attention (decoder) save Tuple(torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor) of
        # all previous decoder key/value_states. Further calls to uni-directional self-attention
        # can concat previous decoder key/value_states to current projected key/value_states (third "elif" case)
        # if encoder bi-directional self-attention `past_key_value` is always `None`
        past_key_value = (key_layer, value_layer)

    if self.position_embedding_type == "rotary":
        query_layer, key_layer = self.rotary_embeddings(query_layer, key_layer)

    # Take the dot product between "query" and "key" to get the raw attention scores.
    attention_scores = torch.matmul(query_layer, key_layer.transpose(-1, -2))

    if self.position_embedding_type == "relative_key" or self.position_embedding_type == "relative_key_query":
        seq_length = hidden_states.size()[1]
        position_ids_l = torch.arange(seq_length, dtype=torch.long, device=hidden_states.device).view(-1, 1)
        position_ids_r = torch.arange(seq_length, dtype=torch.long, device=hidden_states.device).view(1, -1)
        distance = position_ids_l - position_ids_r
        positional_embedding = self.distance_embedding(distance + self.max_position_embeddings - 1)
        positional_embedding = positional_embedding.to(dtype=query_layer.dtype)  # fp16 compatibility

        if self.position_embedding_type == "relative_key":
            relative_position_scores = torch.einsum("bhld,lrd->bhlr", query_layer, positional_embedding)
            attention_scores = attention_scores + relative_position_scores
        elif self.position_embedding_type == "relative_key_query":
            relative_position_scores_query = torch.einsum("bhld,lrd->bhlr", query_layer, positional_embedding)
            relative_position_scores_key = torch.einsum("bhrd,lrd->bhlr", key_layer, positional_embedding)
            attention_scores = attention_scores + relative_position_scores_query + relative_position_scores_key

    if attention_mask is not None:
        # Apply the attention mask is (precomputed for all layers in EsmModel forward() function)
        attention_scores = attention_scores + attention_mask

    # Normalize the attention scores to probabilities.
    attention_probs = nn.functional.softmax(attention_scores, dim=-1)

    # This is actually dropping out entire tokens to attend to, which might
    # seem a bit unusual, but is taken from the original Transformer paper.
    attention_probs = self.dropout(attention_probs)

    # Mask heads if we want to
    if head_mask is not None:
        attention_probs = attention_probs * head_mask

    context_layer = torch.matmul(attention_probs, value_layer)

    context_layer = context_layer.permute(0, 2, 1, 3).contiguous()
    new_context_layer_shape = context_layer.size()[:-2] + (self.all_head_size,)
    context_layer = context_layer.view(new_context_layer_shape)

    outputs = (context_layer, attention_probs) if output_attentions else (context_layer,)

    if self.is_decoder:
        outputs = outputs + (past_key_value,)
    return outputs
```

How would you change the code to replace with the pytorch function sdpa at https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention.html#torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention, specifically, how/could you change the relative positional encoding into a attention mask that could be passed on to the function? Scouring online it seems possible, meaning the scaled_dot_product_attention function can expect an arbitrary mask but not sure how this would be achieved in this case.